# Getting a signal when the session terminates in Python

Tags: python, linux, signals

I am trying to write a Python demon which reacts to the end of a session (i.e. TTY is closed because bash has been exited, etc.). From what I understand, a SIGHUP should be sent to the process at some point (I'm fuzzy on the specifics), but I haven't been able to catch anything so far.

Here's my non-functional python attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import signal
import time

def log_to_disk(signum, frame):
        with open("/tmp/SIGNAL", "w") as f:
                f.write("Received %d!\n" % signum)

def fork():
        try:
                pid = os.fork()
                if pid > 0:
                        # Exit parent
                        print "Parent exiting. Bye!"
                        sys.exit(0)
        except OSError as e:
                print "Error while forking! (%s)" % str(e)
                sys.exit(1)

fork()
os.chdir('/')
os.setsid()
os.umask(0)
fork()  # Second fork.

# Catch ALL the signals just in case.
for i in [x for x in dir(signal) if x.startswith("SIG")]:
  try:
    signum = getattr(signal, i)
    signal.signal(signum, log_to_disk)
  except Exception as e:
    print "Couldn't handle %s (%s)." % (i, str(e))
while True:
        time.sleep(10)
```

What I'm doing: I SSH into a server, launch the script there, then close my SSH session. Then I log back in, hoping that the `/tmp/SIGNAL` file will have been created, but no luck so far. If I send a signal to the process with `kill`, the file appears so I'm assuming this is not an issue with the handler.
I've also tried forking only once and/or commenting out the `chdir/setsid/umask` part, but I haven't received anything then either.
Another avenue I've explored is forking only once and trying to write to the TTY periodically, expecting to receive a SIGTTOU at some point when it's closed.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to find a workaround, which is to detect when `stdout` cannot be resolved to a TTY name anymore:

```
import os
import sys
import time

def fork():
        try:
                pid = os.fork()
                if pid > 0:
                        # Exit parent
                        print "Parent exiting. Bye!"
                        sys.exit(0)
        except OSError as e:
                print "Error while forking! (%s)" % e.message
                sys.exit(1)

fork()
os.chdir('/')
os.setsid()
os.umask(0)
fork()  # Second fork.

while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        with open("/tmp/SIGNAL", "a+") as f:
                try:
                        os.ttyname(1)  # 1 = stdout
                except:
                        f.write("The session has been shut down :)\n")
                        sys.exit(0)
```

I'm still not sure what exactly is going on: when I look at the Python process in `ps`, the TTY column shows a question mark (?), so I don't see how it can still be able to resolve its stdout after the double-fork.
I'll also keep this question open for a little while longer in case anyone comes up with an answer which works in shells with no TTY!